# Joi.date() date value is looks different in database

Tags: database, typescript, date, validation, joi

Validation:

date: Joi.date().label('Date'),

i am using postman and when i post

"date": "10-03-2022"

it looks like this

"date": "2022-10-02T21:00:00.000Z"

How can I solve this different appearance problem? I am writing with TypeScript.

Comment: i can add screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the problem.
It's happening because of the Time Zone difference.

Comment: Did you solved it? Maybe adding a bit more information on you anwer would be more helpful to others. Or maybe instead of an answer you should have added this as a comment on your question.